# AWS data transfer: unexplained region

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I have started using AWS this month and notice from the billing > data transfer section that I have been charged for some data transfer between regions, eg. "AWS Data Transfer USE1-APN1-AWS-Out-Bytes".

However, I have only ever used EC2 and S3 services and launched EC2 instances in US East. My only S3 bucket is US East and private. I'm puzzled as to where this transfer comes from. How do I go about finding out?

Comment: Is this for EC2 or S3 usage? The billing code is for data transfer from us-east-1 to ap-northeast-1. I don't know the answer to this question: If another AWS customer downloads a public file from your S3 bucket with a resource (e.g. EC2) in AWS, would the billing statement show a region to region data transfer charge or a regular data transfer charge?

Comment: See this: https://www.quora.com/In-AWS-EC2-what-counts-towards-data-transfer-costs

Comment: @JohnHanley I'll bet that's it.  There's no documented differentiation between cross-account and same-account traffic when the traffic is cross-region within AWS.